# Free FoxPro DB to SQL Server DB sync tool

Tags: sql-server, foxpro

Which software can you recommend to sync data from a **FoxPro** source to a **SQL Server** destination?

Comment: Just a one-time "migration"-type sync, or an ongoing sync? Only one-way, from FoxPro to SQL Server, or two-way (back to Foxpro as well) ??

Comment: -ongoing sync, foxpro db are local, they are located in other regions. Sql server is central db system. they must be added and updated if row changed each month;

-one-way: from foxPro to Sql Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple links with information that might be of help:

[Migrating From Visual FoxPro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415061/migrating-from-visual-foxpro)

[VFP conversion to support SQL server Backend](http://nationalcom.com/home/download/Conversion-VFP-SQLServer.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

At my company we have data being written to foxpro tables daily, and are synced to SQL Server nightly using SSIS, so for the actual conversion I recommend that.

Getting the foxpro data to your central location could be accomplished by transferring the foxpro files via FTP (we've done this for years), or you could set up some sort of Web Service.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find a tool to do this automatically and on a scheduled basis especially if they are geographically remote and the sync has to happen over the public internet. I'd be looking at writing a web service of some sort, which will sit on a server on the VFP side with methods to expose the VFP data, and another service on the SQL Server side to access that web service periodically and perform CRUD operations.

Comment: I don't think you'd want to set up a web service at each foxpro site.   I've thought about doing that before, and even for a few sites it seems like a lot of maintenance.